# What are the parameters to be passed in this Azure Storage account containers rest API?

Tags: azure, postman, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azure-rest-api

API link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-containers2?tabs=azure-ad#Request

[image]

If I try without headers (token), I'm getting the below error:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>ResourceNotFound</Code>
    <Message>The specified resource does not exist.
RequestId:<guid_id>
Time:2023-06-30T08:03:13.9508663Z</Message>
</Error>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I have reproduced the issue at my environment and able to get the result by using** `https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/?comp=list` **URL**.

I have generated the Bearer token like below, mention the resource name as `https://storage.azure.com` while you are requesting for a token.

[image]

Then called `https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/?comp=list` URL by including `x-ms-version: 2017-11-09` in the header along with the Bearer Token.

[image]

Please refer [ms docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-azure-active-directory).

Comment: I took the bearer token through Developer Tools in the browser page of Azure Storage Account - https://i.imgur.com/GgHE63m.png and passed the headers same like you - https://i.imgur.com/Bo0xdkB.png - didn't get the result

Comment: try to generate the token using Azure AD as documented here in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-azure-active-directory and alike my approach

Comment: I can't create in your approach as we do not have permission to create App registration in our organization. This takes lot of time to get it approval for creation. Any other way to get the bearer token?

Comment: @Afrin, What access do you have to get the above result and what is the least RBAC required to get the same?

Comment: I having Contributor access

Comment: We too have Contributor access but its customized. We cannot create or see SAS and other few operations in the storage account.

Comment: So, do we have any other approach to get the bearer token or can you try with my approach and check

Comment: according to MS documentation, you can only send authorized request to storage account in 3 ways- 1. Azure AD(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-azure-active-directory)  2. Shared key(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-shared-key)  3. Delegate access with SAS(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/service-sas-examples). Among all easiest way to get the token is Azure AD. Try to get the required access to create App registration.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254313/discussion-between-ikhtesam-afrin-and-profiler).

Comment: By trying my approach, we're able to get the result for this [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/blob-containers/list?tabs=HTTP) but failing for this [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-containers2?tabs=azure-ad#Request).